# Error using "repository-s3" plugin for ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-s3, elasticsearch-plugin

I'm trying to set the configuration for snapshot repository of elasticsearch nodes to S3.

I have installed the **"repository-s3"** plugin for elasticsearch.

```
PUT http://<username>:<password>@<elasticsearch-instance-ip>:9200/_snapshot/s3_repository?verify=false

    {
      "type": "s3",
      "settings": {
        "bucket": "bucket-name",
        "region": "eu-west-1",
        "access_key": "****",
        "secret_key": "****"
    }
}
```

and the response is:

```
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "repository_exception",
                "reason": "[s3_repository] failed to create repository"
            }
        ],
        "type": "repository_exception",
        "reason": "[s3_repository] failed to create repository",
        "caused_by": {
            "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
            "reason": "Setting [access_key] is insecure, but property [allow_insecure_settings] is not set"
        }
    },
    "status": 500
}
```

I have tried applying allow_insecure_settings setting in the `elasticsearch.yml` configuration file but that does not work.

FYI I'm using `X-Pack` plugin

Any suggestions?

Comment: What version were you using back then?

Answer (score 12):

```
vim config/jvm.options
```

Add the below line:

`-Des.allow_insecure_settings=true`

It is working for me. there is an undocumented system property: 
https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/26589

Comment: It's worth noting that this should be set on all nodes in the ES cluster.

Comment: works! I added this option to jvm.options file and restarted node

Answer (score 1):

In my case, setting of `bin/elasticsearch-keystore add s3.client.default.access_key` and `.secret_key` fixed this issue.

Comment: Which elasticsearch version?

Comment: ES version - 6.7.0